# c# mvvm IEqualityComparer with IChangeTracking

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, equality, change-tracking

I am trying to achieve following:
I have a form where user has to input Name, Surname, Address, ... together with Save Changes button.
I want to enable user to click **Save Changes** button only if he has really made any changes. I found that by simply using IChangeTracking it only tracks whether user has done **any** change to the tool, but shall he revert the changes back, this is no longer reflected. Due to that, whenever I see that the change has been made, I fire IEqualityComparer; however with no luck as it gives me the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.

Here is my simple class Person:

```
public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _Surname;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set
        {
            _Surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModelBase structure:

> ```
> public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IChangeTracking, IEqualityComparer<Person>
> {
>     public event Action ValueChanged;
>     protected ViewModelBase()
>     {
>         this.PropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged);
>         ValueChanged += ViewModelBase_ValueChanged;
>     }
>
>     void ViewModelBase_ValueChanged() {/*do nothing*/ }
>
>     public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
>     {
>         if (x == null || y == null)
>             return false;
>
>         return (x.Name == y.Name && x.Surname == y.Surname);
>     }
>
>     public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
>     {
>         return obj.GetHashCode();
>     }
>
>     private void OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e != null && !String.Equals(e.PropertyName, "IsChanged", StringComparison.Ordinal))
>         {
>             this.IsChanged = true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void AcceptChanges()
>     {
>         this.IsChanged = false;
>     }
>
>     public bool IsChanged
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
>             {
>                 return _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
>             }
>         }
>
>         set
>         {
>             lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
>             {
>                     _notifyingObjectIsChanged = value;
>
>                     this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChanged");
>
>                     this.ValueChanged.Invoke();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     private bool _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
>     private readonly object _notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot = new Object();
>
>     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
>     protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
>     {
>         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
>         if (handler != null)
>         {
>             handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));//<<<<<Mentioned Error occures here
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

And finally here is how I set up my ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Person osoba { get; set; }
    public Person OldOsoba { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        osoba = new Person();
        osoba.Name = "John";
        osoba.Surname = "Doe";
        osoba.AcceptChanges();

        OldOsoba = new Person();
        OldOsoba.Name = "John";
        OldOsoba.Surname = "Doe";
        OldOsoba.AcceptChanges();

        osoba.ValueChanged += osoba_ValueChanged;
    }

    void osoba_ValueChanged()
    {
        osoba.IsChanged = osoba.Equals(OldOsoba);
    }
}
```

I am open to any suggestions, as I am not quite sure if this was the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

In your models create an **IsDirty** property, which will be set to true if the Name, or Surname properties change:

```
public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
    public string OldName { get; set; }
    public string OldSurname { get; set; }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty");
        }
    }

    private string _Surname;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set
        {
            _Surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty");
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get 
        { 
           return this.Name != this.OldName && this.Surname != this.OldSurname; 
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: It might be a good idea to use an interface for IsDirty property, or even a base class.*

Then, you can implement a command for your ViewModel which will test if any of the people in the list have been changed:

```
public class SaveChangesCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public SaveChangesCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //People should be an ObservableCollection<Person> in your view model.
        return _viewModel.People.Any(x => x.IsDirty);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Create an instance of this command in your view model:

```
public SaveChangesCommand SaveChangesCommand { get; set; }
```

*Don't forget to instantiate it (In your constructor would be a good place)*

And bind a button to it in your view:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}" Content="Save Changes"/>
```

Now, with this all together, when any of your models become dirty, the save changes button will become enabled. Once clicked, it will call a **SaveChanges** method in your view model. Here you will need to implement the save changes implementation and reset all models back to their default state (IsDirty = false)

I'd advise working through the MVVM tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, however I do not understand how to connect IsDirty property with **IEqualityComparer** or **IChangeTracking**?

Comment: My thinking was that you were trying to save changes only if a person's properties had been changed.

In my suggestion, there is no need for IEqualityComparer, or IChangeTracking, as the IsDirty property takes care of that for you.

All you need to do is check if a person is IsDirty = true, and if they are, then save that person's changes.

Comment: I apologize for wrong explanation - I am trying to disable Save Button if user has not made any changes. He may have changed value of some property (e.g. name), but if he changes it back to the original, Save button should be disabled as there was no change in the data

Comment: This is fine, a slight alternation to the model that I proposed should solve the problem. Bare with me while I edit the response.

Comment: Thank you, I marked it as solved; question though - is there a way how to do the same comparison without storing old values in the same object? As you can see from my original post I have two **Person()** classes - **osoba** and **Oldosoba**, where Oldosoba is backup of all original values. Is it possible to somehow 'listen' to PropertyChanged of osoba in my ViewModel and when it has been fired I call comparator?

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe to the PropertyChanged event, and the sender argument will be the Person that was changed. However you have to be careful when doing stuff like that, due to reference and value types. In my personal experience, keeping values inside objects that belong to them is generally a good idea. That said, good luck! :-)